# Как прекратить принимать данные в телеграмм боте?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Дорогие программисты, я изучаю создание ботов телеграмме и хотел написать теле-бота который пишет количество кубков имеет этот человек в игре "brawl stars", написав его тег, сперва пользователь пишет команду */start*, и после этого он должен написать свой тег и ему пишется его количество кубков. И я хотел создать еще другую команду */club*, после его написание показывалась в каком клубе чел находится, и **проблема в том что телеграмм бот при вводе */club* думает что тег игрока**, и пишет про тег игрока, а надо чтобы бот закрыл команду */start* и начал другую обрабодку команды */club*. вот код:

```
import brawlstats
import telebot


#токены
bot = telebot.TeleBot("токен для телеги")
client = brawlstats.Client(
    'токен для бравл API')

#команда бота /start
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>Напишите свой тег в бравле</b>\n1. без хештега\n2. тег должен состоят не меньше 9 сиволов ', parse_mode="html")
    
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
    def mess(message):
        get_message_bot = message.text.strip()
        try:
            player = client.get_profile(get_message_bot)
            club = player.get_club()
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"<b>Имя: </b>{player.name}"
                                                 f"\n<b>Кубки: </b>{player.trophies} \U0001F3C6",
                                                 parse_mode="html")

        except Exception as E:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "<b>Вы ввели не правильно свой тег</b>", parse_mode="html")

#команда бота /club
@bot.message_handler(commands=["club"])
def club(message):
    if club is not None:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Вы в клубе: {club.name}", parse_mode="html")
    else: 
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"вы не каком либо клубе")
```

Забыл сказать что пользователь должен писать с перва /start что бы бот узнал профиль игрока потом мог писать /club. Буду благодарен если ответите на мой вопрос, и если вы не поняли что я имеел виду пожалуйста не ставьте -1, пишите в комментарии

Comment: При подключении к боту и так автоматически будет отослано /start. А так, вам нужно хранить состояния для юзеров, чтобы проверять является ли команда правильной или перед ее вызовом нужно еще что-то сделать

Comment: НИКОГДА! слышите? НИКОГДА не пихайте обработчик в обработчик! commands = start и contnent_types = text не могут быть внутри друг друга.

Comment: тогда что заместо "content_types" = text???